# How to override node level properties of ACE app in OpenShift?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-integration-bus, palantir-for-ibm-cloudpak-for-data

In IIB, we can generate a properties file from a bar and use that file to override the node-level properties like MQ input/output host, port, etc. during deployment. Still, I know that each node-level property, like parsing options, can't be overridden at runtime but can be overridden only at deployment time. So, is there any way to override the node-level properties in the ACE app running in OpenShift on ACE operator?

[image: Below is the props i wanna override]